# Celery: Provide different config files

Tags: python, celery

I want to create celery workers with different configuration.

I use the following command to create worker threads:

```
celery worker -A proj -l info --config=celeryconfig2.py -Ofair -n worker2.%h 

celery worker -A proj -l info --config=celeryconfig.py -Ofair -n worker.%h
```

However, this creates both worker threads with config as celeryconfig.py.

I have the following structure of my project:

```
scripts/
   proj/
     -- celery.py
     -- celeryconfig.py
     -- celeryconfig2.py
     -- __init__.py
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When loading celery configuration from command line, you should give configuration module name **not** file name.

So you have to start worker like this from **the folder where your config is present.**

```
celery worker -A proj -l info --config=celeryconfig
celery worker -A proj -l info --config=celeryconfig2
```

Alternatively, you can also give module path like

```
celery worker -A proj -l info --config=foo.bar.celeryconfig
```

but not like this

```
celery worker -A proj -l info --config=celeryconfig.py
celery worker -A proj -l info --config=celeryconfig2.pt
```

Comment: This gives the following error:
ImportError: No module named celeryconfig

Comment: Are you starting worker from the directory where `celeryconfig.py` is present? Which celery version are you using?

Comment: I am starting celery from where proj folder is present. I ran 
celery worker -A proj -l info --config=proj.celeryconfig which works now. 
Thanks!
Can you update this in your answer?